# Use shell symbols in directory path

Tags: c++, shell, filepath

I want to open a file with my program, and I want to use shell symbols to make it easier for me to locate the file. Is there an easy way to have the shell expand out my file path before I use it on runtime. I'm looking for a function that does this.

`~/.foo.bar` -> `/home/someuser/.foo.bar`

Is there some easy way to have the shell preprocess the paths to files before opening the file?

Comment: I believe [wordexp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp) does that.

Comment: @Jashaszun It does not.

Comment: From a commandline you can use echo and let bash evaluate it. Calling it from C++ without invoking bash will skip the shell expansions. Try using bash as the command and echo the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [wordexp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp):

```
#include <wordexp.h>

std::string wordexp(std::string var, int flags = 0)
{
    wordexp_t p;
    if(!wordexp(var.c_str(), &p, flags))
    {
        if(p.we_wordc && p.we_wordv[0])
            var = p.we_wordv[0];
        wordfree(&p);
    }
    return var;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << wordexp("~/test") << '\n';
}
```