# Why is fstream not working for writing files in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, api, fstream, ofstream

`fstream` does not work for writing files in Linux, using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>                     //for console input and output
#include <fstream>                      //for file input and output

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::ofstream outFile("~/test_ws/src/data_logger/src/myFile.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    outFile.open("~/test_ws/src/data_logger/src/myFile.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if(outFile.is_open()) {
        outFile << "Writing whether you like it or not.\n";
        std::cout << "YES!\n";
    } else std::cout << "Nope!\n";
    outFile.close();
}
```

What is the problem? Alternatively, is there another C++ API that I can use for writing files in Linux?

Comment: _"fstream does not work for writing files in Linux"_ Huh what please?? Of course that works well in any platform OS. Your error situation might be something else that you didn't tell us.

Comment: I edited the question to instead ask why the code isn't working, but also left your [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/214708) intact. Hint: for future questions, it is usually best not to make assumptions (e.g. instead of "why doesn't the `foo` function work in `bar` language?", try "why is my code using the `foo` function not working?").

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759799/how-to-replace-the-home-directory-with-a-tilde-linux also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035974/use-shell-symbols-in-directory-path also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255940/reference-linux-username-in-string-to-open-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fstream` & co. work perfectly well on Linux. The problem with your code is that you are using `~`, which isn't a "real" path as recognized by C++ `fstream` and in general lower level system calls, but it generally works from the command line as it is expanded *by the shell*.

If you want your program to perform shell-like path expansion, you can call the [`wordexp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html) function; mind you, in many years of working on Linux I don't think I ever needed that, as generally paths come "from the outside" as command arguments, already expanded by the shell (and that's the general assumption, not to be broken to avoid doubly-expanding stuff; `wordexp` has its typical usage when expanding paths e.g. in configuration files).

Comment: Would the downvoter mind to explain?

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I guess I can't use .txt in the filename either.

Comment: @Raisintoe: no, .txt is fine... What problem do you have with it?